# Configuring USB Webcam in Raspberry PI

Tags: usb, webcam, v4l2

I'm configuring Logitech C920 USB Webcam in Raspian for using it with a 3rd party application.
I get the below error
I tried to set exposure control using uvcdynctrl and guvcview as well.
I'm able to use the USB camera with Cheese though.

```
Init USB video source...
[libwebcam] Warning: The driver behind device video0 does not seem to 
support V4L2
[libwebcam] Unsupported V4L2_CID_EXPOSURE_AUTO control with a non-contiguous     range of choice IDs found 
[libwebcam] Invalid or unsupported V4L2 control encountered: ctrl_id = 0x009A0901, name = 'Exposure, Auto'
```

How do I set the exposure control ?

Comment: Have you tried to search for the error?

Comment: Yes, of course, None of them worked so far. The 3rd party application works fine with Raspberry Pi Camera Module. I reset the erroneous values using guvcview as well. Still it doesn't work.